# Callout links not working

Tags: support, broken-link

On the main site, I have suddenly lost my ability to use links which have a callout effect (like `Add Comment`, `View More Comments`, `Flag`, the down arrow by my name, etc).  This still works fine here on meta.

When I click on one of those links on the main site, *nothing happens*.  I checked in Firebug's console, there are no errors on clicking the links.

On load I get the following errors:

```
SyntaxError: syntax error
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV='Pragma' CONTENT='no-cache'>

stub.j...9e79912 (line 1)
ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined
StackExchange.ready(function(){$.get('/posts/17007927/ivc/6565');});

how-to...it-form (line 581)
ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined
StackExchange.ready(function () {

how-to...it-form (line 36)
ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined
...opup":true},"user":{"fkey":"870c0ca95fd24c6a4dda242cc2c9071a","isRegistered":tru...

how-to...it-form (line 43)
ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined
StackExchange.using("gps", function() {

how-to...it-form (line 48)
ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined
StackExchange.ready(function() {

how-to...it-form (line 391)
ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined
StackExchange.ready(function() {

how-to...it-form (line 489)
ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined
...nja.min.css?v=78ccbfa5c59f",window.careers_companycssurl="//cdn-careers.sstatic....

how-to...it-form (line 502)
ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined
StackExchange.ready(function(){$.get('/posts/17007927/ivc/6565');});
```

Comment: Tried clearing your cache?

Comment: @Mat Yes, no effect.  This is FF 21 btw.

Comment: Check the network console, your browser is blocking JS files or fails to load them.

Comment: Also have the same issue (with same errors) in IE 10 on the same machine (I never use IE on this machine, so definitely not a cache issue there)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I'm getting 403 on http://i.stack.imgur.com/SBtDy.gif?s=32&g=1, everything else is 200 (OK) or 304 (Not Modified)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some digging after @ShaWizDowArd suggested a js file not loading properly, turns out FortiClient 5.0.1 (which I use to connect to a work VPN) categorized `cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js?v=e9e6d9e79912` as **Security Risk:Malicious Websites**!  Oddly, if I remove the `?v=e9e6d9e79912`, it goes through fine.

It *kindly* returned a remediation page with a 200 status code so I couldn't easily tell it wasn't working without inspecting each response individually.

I submitted the site for re-review with them... says it can take up to 24 hours.

Comment: Any updates? :)